# Return element(s) from a lengthy list which are present in a length string

Tags: python, search

I am trying to get a subset of a list which containing the element present in a string. I am using the following code which is very slow when we have a large list of elements and large list of strings.

```
for s in string:
    cc=[]
    for e in lst:
        if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(e) + r"\b", s):
        cc.append(e)
```

Can anyone help me to optimize it please? Thanks

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list of search strings into a single regexp with alternatives for each element.

```
regex = re.compile('\b(?:' + '|'.join(re.escape(e) for e in lst) + r')\b')
for s in string:
    cc = set(regex.findall(s))
```